# How can I create a new png image file out of png image file that i compared the colors with a list of colors?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a text file with list of colors:

```
rgb(255, 0, 254) --- 200 mm
rgb(208, 0, 120) --- 100 mm
rgb(225, 10, 18) --- 50 mm
rgb(251, 63, 0) --- 40 mm
rgb(255, 125, 1) --- 30 mm
rgb(255, 168, 0) --- 24 mm
rgb(255, 207, 0) --- 18 mm
rgb(254, 253, 25) --- 13 mm
rgb(124, 255, 33) --- 9.0 mm
rgb(18, 242, 24) --- 6.0 mm
rgb(1, 211, 28) --- 4.0 mm
rgb(0, 176, 44) --- 2.0 mm
rgb(0, 140, 77) --- 1.2 mm
rgb(0, 160, 155) --- 0.7 mm
rgb(0, 195, 201) --- 0.2 mm
rgb(1, 101, 239) --- 0.1 mm
```

I have original png image file with pixels inside in some colors and the colors of the pixels are from the list of the colors in the text file above: the original png image files size is 940x940 and Bit depth 8 the new png image file is also size 940x940 but Bit depth 32

[image: png original image file with pixels in some colors]

now I created a class that read the colors from the text file and the colors from the png image file compare them and create a new png file only from the matching colors between the png image file and the list from the text file.

in my logic the new png image file should be exactly like the original png image file.

the result is that the new png image file have the colors inside but not as the original does.

[image: new png image file]

the class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace Download_Files
{
    public class ProcessImage
    {
        // List to hold colors from the text file
        public List<Color> PredefinedColors { get; set; } = new List<Color>();
        // List to hold colors extracted from the image
        public List<Color> ImageColors { get; set; } = new List<Color>();
        // List to hold colors that are equal between the image and the predefined list
        public List<Color> MatchingColors { get; set; } = new List<Color>();

        public ProcessImage(string colorsFilePath)
        {
            LoadPredefinedColors(colorsFilePath);
        }

        private void LoadPredefinedColors(string filePath)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var colorParts = line.Split(new[] { "rgb(", ",", ")", "---" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (colorParts.Length >= 3)
                {
                    int r = int.Parse(colorParts[0].Trim());
                    int g = int.Parse(colorParts[1].Trim());
                    int b = int.Parse(colorParts[2].Trim());
                    PredefinedColors.Add(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
                }
            }
        }

        public void Process(string imagePath, int tolerance = 10)
        {
            // Load the image
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imagePath))
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
                BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
                IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
                int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
                byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

                // Process the pixel data with tolerance
                for (int i = 0; i < rgbValues.Length; i += 4) // ARGB format
                {
                    Color color = Color.FromArgb(rgbValues[i + 2], rgbValues[i + 1], rgbValues[i]);
                    ImageColors.Add(color);

                    foreach (var predefinedColor in PredefinedColors)
                    {
                        if (IsColorMatch(color, predefinedColor, tolerance) && !MatchingColors.Contains(predefinedColor))
                        {
                            MatchingColors.Add(predefinedColor);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsColorMatch(Color color1, Color color2, int tolerance)
        {
            return Math.Abs(color1.R - color2.R) <= tolerance &&
                   Math.Abs(color1.G - color2.G) <= tolerance &&
                   Math.Abs(color1.B - color2.B) <= tolerance;
        }

        public void CreateImageWithMatchingColors(string savePath)
        {
            int imageSize = 940;
            int colorBlockSize = imageSize / MatchingColors.Count; // Calculate block size for each color

            using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(imageSize, imageSize))
            {
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < MatchingColors.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // Create a brush for each matching color
                        using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(MatchingColors[i]))
                        {
                            // Calculate the position and size of the color block
                            int yPosition = i * colorBlockSize;
                            graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, yPosition, imageSize, colorBlockSize);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Save the new image as a PNG
                newImage.Save(savePath, ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }

        public void ProcessAndSaveImage(string imagePath, string savePath)
        {
            Process(imagePath);
            CreateImageWithMatchingColors(savePath);
        }
    }
}
```

the form1 usage:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeCustomComponents();
}
#endregion

#region UI Initialization
private void InitializeCustomComponents()
{
    // Initialization logic...
    string colorsFilePath = @"d:\filteredColorsWithValues.txt";
    string originalImagePath = @"d:\test1.png";
    string savePath = @"d:\filteredTest1.png";

    ProcessImage processImage = new ProcessImage(colorsFilePath);
    processImage.Process(originalImagePath);
    processImage.CreateImageWithMatchingColors(savePath); 
}
```

but since the result is not what i wanted , i want to have exactly like a copy of the original png image file i tried to change the class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace Download_Files
{
    public class ProcessImage
    {
        public List<Color> PredefinedColors { get; set; } = new List<Color>();
        public List<Color> MatchingColors { get; set; } = new List<Color>();

        public ProcessImage(string colorsFilePath)
        {
            LoadPredefinedColors(colorsFilePath);
        }

        private void LoadPredefinedColors(string filePath)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var colorParts = line.Split(new[] { "rgb(", ",", ")", "---" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (colorParts.Length >= 3)
                {
                    int r = int.Parse(colorParts[0].Trim());
                    int g = int.Parse(colorParts[1].Trim());
                    int b = int.Parse(colorParts[2].Trim());
                    PredefinedColors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b)); // Assuming opacity is always 255
                }
            }
        }

        public void Process(string imagePath, int tolerance = 10)
        {
            // Load the image
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imagePath))
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
                BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
                IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
                int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
                byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

                // Process the pixel data with tolerance
                // Process the pixel data with tolerance
                for (int i = 0; i < rgbValues.Length; i += 4) // Assuming ARGB format
                {
                    Color color = Color.FromArgb(rgbValues[i + 3], rgbValues[i + 2], rgbValues[i + 1], rgbValues[i]);
                    foreach (Color predefinedColor in PredefinedColors)
                    {
                        if (IsColorMatch(color, predefinedColor, tolerance))
                        {
                            MatchingColors.Add(predefinedColor);
                            break; // Stop checking other predefined colors if a match is found
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void CreateFilteredColorImage(string originalImagePath, string savePath)
        {
            using (Bitmap originalImage = new Bitmap(originalImagePath))
            {
                // Assuming the original image is 8-bit depth, we need to create a new image with the same format
                using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height, originalImage.PixelFormat))
                {
                    // If the original image has a color palette (8-bit depth), we copy it
                    if (originalImage.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed)
                    {
                        ColorPalette palette = newImage.Palette;
                        for (int i = 0; i < palette.Entries.Length; i++)
                        {
                            palette.Entries[i] = originalImage.Palette.Entries[i];
                        }
                        newImage.Palette = palette;
                    }

                    // ... existing code for setting pixels ...
                    newImage.Save(savePath, ImageFormat.Png);
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsColorMatch(Color color1, Color color2, int tolerance)
        {
            // Check if the colors are similar within the given tolerance
            return Math.Abs(color1.R - color2.R) <= tolerance &&
                   Math.Abs(color1.G - color2.G) <= tolerance &&
                   Math.Abs(color1.B - color2.B) <= tolerance &&
                   color1.A == color2.A; // Assuming you want to match the alpha channel exactly
        }
    }
}
```

and the form1 usage:

```
string colorsFilePath = @"d:\filteredColorsWithValues.txt";
string originalImagePath = @"d:\test1.png";
string savePath = @"d:\filteredTest1.png";

ProcessImage processImage = new ProcessImage(colorsFilePath);
processImage.Process(originalImagePath);
processImage.CreateFilteredColorImage(originalImagePath, savePath);
```

now the new png image file is empty:

it looks black on the hard drive but when i edit it with paint it's blank white empty:

| [image: empty new png image file] |
| --- |

Comment: Your first image (Vt1gS.png) has the PixelFormat `Format32bppArgb` and not `Format8bppIndexed` as you claim.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes maybe i did a mistake but i just downloaded the first image again from my message here my question and it is Bit depth 8 the second image is 32. i mean this image is 8 https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lUyQ.png with the pixels more scattered.  the second one is indeed 32 https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqMfi.png

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes but i'm not sure if this is even the problem ,  the Bit depth.

Comment: Why not simply replace the values in the `rgbValues[]` locked bytes, and write that back to a file?

Comment: The `IsColorMatch` method currently returns the first color that falls within tolerance, and the color is ignored if there is no match. A better approach might be to return the color with the smallest difference.

Comment: @Loathing can you show me example please how to write back the rgbValues[] to a new file ? i want to write only matching colors.

Comment: Sure, I'll post a sample answer within an hour.

Comment: @Loathing i tried your answer it's almost perfect.  if you can look at my comment on your answer please.

Comment: I think that the scientifically correct way of solving this problem is to first translate the original image into precipitation levels. Even better: use the original precipitation data instead of an already color coded image. Then you need a map that attributes colors to precipitation levels ranges. E.g. [>= 30 mm ... < 40 mm] equals this color, next range [>=40 mm ... < 50 mm] equals that color.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes show me that example also if possible. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code filters the image based on the hue, and a hue tolerance range.

[image: Preciptation Filter Form]

```
public static void SampleCode() {   
        
    String imageFilename = @"C:\temp\test2.png";
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(imageFilename);
    //Bitmap bmp3 = BitmapHandler.LoadBitmap(File.ReadAllBytes(imageFilename));

    Label lbHue = new Label { Text = "Hue", AutoSize = true, Anchor = AnchorStyles.None };
    TrackBar trackBarHue = new TrackBar { Minimum = 0, Maximum = 360, MinimumSize = new Size(720, 0) };
    Label lbHueTolerance = new Label { Text = "Hue Tolerance", AutoSize = true, Anchor = AnchorStyles.None };
    NumericUpDown nudHueTolerance = new NumericUpDown { Minimum = 0, Maximum = 50, Value = 25, Anchor = AnchorStyles.None, AutoSize = true };
    PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage };
    
    FlowLayoutPanel p1 = new FlowLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Top, AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink, WrapContents = false };
    p1.Controls.Add(lbHue);
    p1.Controls.Add(trackBarHue);
    p1.Controls.Add(lbHueTolerance);
    p1.Controls.Add(nudHueTolerance);
    Form f = new Form { Size = new Size(1000, 900), StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen };
    f.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
    f.Controls.Add(p1);

    float maxHue = float.MinValue;
    int stride = 0;
    byte[] rgbValues = GetPixelArray(bmp, out stride);
    for (int i = 0; i < rgbValues.Length; i += 4) {
        int b = rgbValues[i];
        int g = rgbValues[i + 1];
        int r = rgbValues[i + 2];

        Color c = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
        float h = c.GetHue();
        if (h > maxHue && h < 350)
            maxHue = h;
    }

    trackBarHue.Value = 0;
    trackBarHue.Maximum = (int) Math.Ceiling(maxHue);
    lbHue.Text = String.Format("Hue [{0} to {1}]", trackBarHue.Minimum, trackBarHue.Maximum);

    pictureBox.Image = bmp;

    trackBarHue.ValueChanged += delegate {
        if (trackBarHue.Value == 0)
            pictureBox.Image = bmp;
        else {
            Bitmap newBitmap = CreateNewImage(bmp, trackBarHue.Value, (int) nudHueTolerance.Value);
            Image oldImage = pictureBox.Image;
            pictureBox.Image = newBitmap;
            if (oldImage != bmp)
                oldImage.Dispose();
        }
    };

    Application.Run(f);
    bmp.Dispose();
}


public static Bitmap CreateNewImage(Bitmap bmp, int hue, int tolerance) {
    int stride = 0;
    byte[] rgbValues = GetPixelArray(bmp, out stride);
    for (int i = 0; i < rgbValues.Length; i += 4) {
        int b = rgbValues[i];
        int g = rgbValues[i + 1];
        int r = rgbValues[i + 2];
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
        float h = c.GetHue();
        if (h >= 350) h = 0; // wrap around case
        if (Math.Abs(h - hue) > tolerance) {
            rgbValues[i] = 0;
            rgbValues[i + 1] = 0;
            rgbValues[i + 2] = 0;
            rgbValues[i + 3] = 0;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, bmp.PixelFormat);
    CopyPixelsToBitmap(rgbValues, bmp2);
    return bmp2;
}

///<summary>
/// Note: The color order of PixelFormat is:
/// Format24bppRgb:   [B, G, R, B, G, R, ... ]
/// Format32bppPArgb: [B, G, R, A, B, G, R, A, ... ]
/// Format32bppRgb:   [B, G, R, 255, B, G, R, 255, ... ]
/// Format32bppArgb:  [B, G, R, A, B, G, R, A, ... ] (Bitmaps 'A' is always 255).
/// For Format24bppRgb, the stride is not always a whole multiple of the width. An image might be 150 pixels wide, but have a stride length of 452.
///</summary>
public static byte[] GetPixelArray(Bitmap bmp, out int stride) {
    int w = bmp.Width;
    int h = bmp.Height;
    BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
    IntPtr pointer = data.Scan0;
    stride = data.Stride; // stride = (bytes per pixel) x (w)
    int size = stride * h; 
    byte[] pixels = new byte[size];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pointer, pixels, 0, size);
    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
    return pixels;
}


private static void CopyPixelsToBitmap(byte[] pixels, Bitmap bmp) {
    Rectangle boundsRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(boundsRect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

    Marshal.Copy(pixels, 0, ptr, pixels.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
}
```

Comment: i tried it but the pixels in the new png image not the same exactly like in the original.  and if i look at the original png image properties now i see that the image is Bith depth 8 and not 32 but i'm not sure if it's matter.  i put here in the link i put the two images side by side.  the left one is the new created image file on the right is the original.  you can see the new one is with black background and that the pixels not exactly like the on the right.  https://imgur.com/a/3nK0QvK

Comment: and in this link i added the original png image file. all my images are png and Bit depth 8.   and size 940x940  https://1drv.ms/i/c/3b8a7d9f66ff985b/ERqEiviGHD9ArgYvTzsx4YoBseXNo24kySPLYK-uFu08KQ?e=X1WBaO

Comment: and maybe you can also show me the HSL  version if it should be better ?   sorry for the mess.

Comment: To clarify your goal. You want to keep the original colors, but only if they are "close" to a color inside the text file. Is that correct? If this is correct, then for pixels that are not "close", what color should they be changed to? If this is not correct, then maybe you can elaborate on the goal.

Comment: wait let me clarify.

Comment: i  have list of 500 images.  they are all 940x940 and Bit depth 8.  each png image have different colored pixels in different positions.  the images png images are weather radar images.  all the png images are transparent.  my final goal will be and should be to loop over the images and from each png image to create more copies png copies but each copy will display only one level of color from the original image.  for example if in png there are 5 colors can be many pixels. let me continue explain in next comment.

Comment: but only 5 colors i want to create 5 images from that png file each png will display the pixels of each color. 
and if another png have pixels but with one color or 13 colors then create out of it one copy with the pixels with that color in that case it will be the same image but if there are 13 colors in image then create out of it 13 images each one will be with the pixels of each color only.  that's why i want to compare each image colors to the list because the list present the millimeters by colors.  this way i create from each image a level of millimeters.

Comment: i know it's hard to understand and it's hard for me to explain.  the goal is to create from each png image number of copies of each millimeters levels of pixels from the list of colors.  so each image will have only the pixels colored of the millimeters level from the list.

Comment: sorry for the mess i think my last comment one before this one explain best what i want to do.

Comment: okay, i'm reading these comments

Comment: look at thins link i uploaded another png image just to show you it with different colors you can see here also red and yellow colors.  so if we compare the colors in this image with the list we wil get more colors levels and then the application should create more copies levels.  one image will have the pixels only in blue second only images with pixels in green then yellow then red.  this logic. https://imgur.com/a/q4YQsda

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. You want to take a weather radar image, and filter it so that it only shows a specific precipitation level, like 0.1mm. Is that correct?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: I changed the code to filter the image based on the hue. The hue corresponds to the basic color spectrum (red, orange, yellow, blue indigo, violet). The image in screenshot uses the "q4YQsda" imgur link image.  Let me know if that is getting closer to the answer.

Comment: i added a button to form1 when i click the button getting exception error on the line ImageColorFilter.SampleCode(); System.InvalidOperationException: 'SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.'
i have picturebox1 in form1 and in the button click event i click on it after the form1 is loaded and the application is running.  only then i call the code in the class.  this is the class code:  https://pastebin.com/j2gYK8di

Comment: Delete the two lines in the code that start with `Application.`

Comment: i created a new form in my project and added the controls just like you did in the answer.  my pictureBox size is 940x940  but when i move the slider of the trackBar only one tick to the right the whole image is gone.  this is the new form1 code that  i open in through form1 button click event.   when the form first time open and show i see the image in the pictureBox but then when moving the trackBar slider one tick to the right the image is gone the pictureBox is empty.  here is a link to my form code. https://pastebin.com/kVVXKDPY   do you see any problems ?   thank you.

Comment: Scroll the slider to the same position in my screenshot.

Comment: Initially the pictureBox shows the original image. As soon as the slider value is changed, the image is filtered based on the hue and the hue tolerance. Most of the values are green or blue, which is going to be in the middle of the slider.

Comment: working.  very nice.  and yes it's very close to what i wanted.  now i think we should change it so the trackBar maximum will show only the number of filtered colors and not 360.  each time the trackBar maximum should be change depending on the filtered image number of colors.  and then to start the filtering from the second tick when changing the slider.  sound logic ?

Comment: I updated the code.  The UI code can be made faster by caching the hue values of the original image, rather than calculating them each time the slider changes.